LocalProcessingException when rendering ReportViewer in QueueBackgroundWorkItem
I have a function ObterRelatorio responsible for calling another function to render a ReportViewer as follows:
protected virtual byte[] RenderizarRelatorio(string Formato)
{
    ReportViewer rvwDinamico = new ReportViewer();

    this.m_rdl.Position = 0;

    rvwDinamico.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(m_rdl);

    if (this.Parametros != null)
    {
        rvwDinamico.LocalReport.SetParameters(this.Parametros);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> DataSource in this.DataSourceDictionary)
    {
        rvwDinamico.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(DataSource.Key, DataSource.Value));
    }

    rvwDinamico.Visible = false;

    return rvwDinamico.LocalReport.Render(Formato);
}


I need to call this function within a QueueBackgroundWorkItem as shown in the code below to execute the function in the background:
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
{
    ResultadoConsulta = await RealizaConsulta<T>(Parametros);
    iExportacaoRelatorio = iRelatorioGerencial.GerarExcel(ResultadoConsulta, colunasGrid);
    byte[] bytesExcel = iExportacaoRelatorio.ObterRelatorio();
});

However, whenever I call it inside QueueBackgroundWorkItem, I get a LocalProcessingException. When the same function is called synchronously, the error does not occur, and the report is generated.
I also tried changing the execution method to use a Task.Run instead of QueueBackgroundWorkItem, but I started receiving the error:
ReportPublishingException: The Value expression for the textrun ‘txt_18_ValorAprovado.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains a colon or a line terminator. Colons and line terminators are not valid in expressions.

I don’t believe the issue lies with how the value is being passed, as I mentioned earlier, because if the function is called synchronously, the report is generated without errors.
Can anyone help me?

Code behind for the web page HAS to wait, and unless that other task you launch returns the report, then you can't start another task, since it can't reference any controls on the webform. Once the page lifcycle completes (the post-back + round trip), then the page class goes out of scope, is disposed of, and removed from memory. So the code behind + page class ONLY exists for a very short time - the time that code behind is running. Any other task launched that creates output for that page means the main page class code MUST wait for that code to complete, else the page goes out of scope
